# CSS: Flexbox Order not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just cannot figure out why the following is not working.

There's a div#wrapper that's a flexbox with a bunch of divs inside that I want to reverse the order of.

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="one">One<div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="three">Three</div>
  <div id="four">Four</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#one {
  order: 4;
  background-color: gray;
}

#two {
  order: 3;
  background-color: green;
}

#three {
  order: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

#four {
  order: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close your

```
<div id="one">One<div>
```

replace by:

```
<div id="one">One</div>
```

Comment: code editors that highlight matching tag pairs save lives.